# Show/Hide Label (w/ Toggle Button)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I have an application I'm working on where I need a button (upon click) to show/hide a label. I set up the label as an IBOutlet, and the button as an IBAction - but don't really know where to go from here. I'm still very new to cocoa - I figure it's pretty simple but objective-c is daunting to me. Any help (in dummies terms)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this should do.

```
if ([theLabel isHidden]) {
    [theLabel setHidden:NO];
} else {
    [theLabel setHidden:YES];
}
```

You can see the docs for both methods [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSView).

Comment: Wow. Simple enough! Thanks Nikita I would vote that answer up more if I could, works like a charm

Answer (score 6):

There is another way to do that.
You can simply use the "dot notation", it works this way:

```
if(theLabel.hidden == YES) {
     theLabel.hidden = NO;
}
else {
     theLabel.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the *dot operator*?

Comment: No, the _dot notation_ is a way to associate a property to an object, we can write `[Julia age] = 21;` where "Julia" is my object and "age" the property or with _dot notation_ it will be `Julia.age = 18;`

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 3.0

In the Swift Syntax, you can perform the show/hide button as follows, with an updating title string to identify it's state:

```
if (string.isHidden == true) {
   sender.title = "Hide"
    string.isHidden = false
} else {
    sender.title = "Show"
    string.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
theLabel.hidden = !theLabel.hidden
```